# Accessing information about objects in an array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have two classes, `Teacher` and `Pupil`. In the `Teacher` class there is an array list of `Pupil`'s (containing instances of Pupil).
I'd like to do something like:

```
System.out.println(pupils.get(1).getName())
```

where `getName` is a method from the `Pupil` class. However, `pupils.get(1)` does not seem to act as a `Pupil` and won't let me call this method. How should I do it?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Is your array list typed?

Answer (score 1):

[Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) should do the trick. If you define `pupils` as a types list, then `get(int)` should return a `Pupil` object:

```
List<Pupil> pupils = new ArrayList<Pupil>();
// add some data to the list
System.out.println(pupils.get(1).getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

This assumes some basic stuff about your code. Specifically that pupils is a class containing pupil instances. That you can get them using getPupils() as a List/Collection.

```
ArrayList<Pupil> pupilsList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();
for (Pupil p : pupils.getPupils()){
    // add all pupils
    System.out.println("Adding " + pupilsList.add(p));
}

for (int i=0; i < pupilsList.size(); i++){
    // print all pupils
    System.out.println("Name: " + pupilsList.get(i).getName())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define pupils as:

```
List<Pupil> pupils = ...(some initialization)
```

or cast it to Pupil:

```
System.out.println(((Pupil)(pupils.get(1))).getName())
```